# What is FeedSubscriptionsForEntity on Contact?

Tags: apex, contact, entitysubscription

I'm looking through the code base for my organization and I see that there are SOQL references to "FeedSubscriptionsForEntity."

For example:

```
SELECT SubscriberId FROM FeedSubscriptionsForEntity
```

or

```
for (Contact c : contacts) {
     if( c.FeedSubscriptionsForEntity.size() > 0 ) {
      ....
     }
}
```

I tried poking around our org but couldn't find a field with that title. I also looked on Salesforce developer reference but couldn't find anything. The closest reference is [EntitySubscription - Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm).

Could someone explain what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, it's just a subset of EntitySubscription list, but for the given record only (aka related list). It's maintained by Salesforce in the background when users are clicking on 'Follow' (green icon with plus) in a chatter feed to subscribe for updates for the record, or user. Records also can be deleted/added by Apex as with any other entity.